# Can $x^2$ be expressed as an Exponential Function?

Tags: functions

If we are looking at the graph of $x^2$ for $x>0$ is there some way to express this as an exponential function such as $a^{x+h}$. Is there infinetly many ways to express it as an exponential or no ways at all and how can we show this? Visually, to me it seemed that this was possible but I'm not sure on how to prove it.

Comment: The exponential function $a^x$ with $a>1$ grows much faster than $x^2$ (or $x^n$ with any $n>0$).

Comment: Short answer: No. Unless you are speaking of an approximation via an exponential function over a certain range $x_{min} \leq x \leq x_{max}$, this does not work.

Comment: No, it is not possible.

Comment: Higher derivatives of exponential functions have no zeros

Comment: Thanks for the responses. @ihf looking at the higher derivatives of $a^x$ such as the third derivative $a^x(ln(a))^3$ whereas the third derivative of $x^2$ is zero.  Does this tell us that the exponential is growing faster I'm still unsure.

Comment: It proves that $x^2 \ne a^x$ for all $a$.

Comment: Ah yes that’s right thank you for clarifying

Comment: $\displaystyle x^2 = a^{\left[\frac{2\log(x)}{\log(a)}\right]}.$  I don't see how you can find a constant $h$ such that for all $\displaystyle x,~~ (x + h) = \left[\frac{2\log(x)}{\log(a)}\right].$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x^2=|x|^2=\exp(2\ln(|x|)).$ Hence, your question is equivalent to asking if there exists some $A$ such that $Ax\equiv\ln(|x|).$ I think it is easy to see that this is not the case.